# Iterating through object with different defined patterns

Tags: javascript

I don't know if I miss something or it's a hard one to solve. I have an object like this:

```
const questionReferencesUpdate = {

    5:{
         1: "i was send to earth. i was send to her.",
         2: "to mars",
         3: { reference: "To moon.", expectSt: "to moon. to us." } ,
    },

};
```

**5** is for the current slide. we may have multiple slides defined in the object but for simplicity, I just added one.

I want to return an array consists of elements (sentences) in slide 5... So for 1 and 2, we should return this :

```
["i was send to earth", "i was send to her", "to mars"]
```

For the 3 we should only return `expectSt` and ignore the `reference` **(if there is such pattern)**. So the final output should be array of pure sentences like this:

```
["i was send to earth", "i was send to her", "to mars", "to moon", "to us"]
```

It is so much hard to achieve that I can't understand where should I start.

Note that we may have the pattern of 3 or pattern of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to map object [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and flatten arrays into one array.  [splits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on period and prunes spaces.  Prunes empty results for split with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)(Boolean).  Ternary to check if value is string, and then if expectSt exists to try to extract it for processing.

```js
const questionReferencesUpdate = {

    5:{
         1: "i was send to earth. i was send to her.",
         2: "to mars",
         3: { reference: "To moon.", expectSt: "to moon. to us." } ,
    },

};

console.log(
Object.values(questionReferencesUpdate).flatMap(q=>
  Object.values(q).flatMap(s=>
    (typeof s==='string' ? s : s.expectSt || '')
      .split(/\.\s*/).filter(Boolean)))
)
```

Comment: It's more than complex for me but I try this... thanks for the great answer...

Answer (score 1):

As for the comment, your keys are not fixed, so it can be that you have an array or a string.

```
 const object = {
     1: "i was send to earth. i was send to her.",
     2: "to mars",
     3: { reference: "To moon.", expectSt: "to moon. to us." } ,
   };

 let array = Object.values(object);
 array = array.map(value => {
   if(typeof value === 'string') { return value; }
    return value.expectSt;
 })

 //now is an array containing only strings. 
 console.log(array);
```

Comment: If the pattern of 3 was like 1 and 2 then it doesn't work...

Comment: Is the pattern different? In your question you are not saying it

Comment: And that's what made this a complex issue for me...

Comment: I edited my answer. Now it works as long has the inner object contains expectSt

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object after slide number in this function.

```
var slideToArray = (obj) => {
      return Object.keys(obj)
        .sort()
        .map(k => obj[k])
        .reduce((arr, item) => {
          let node = typeof item === string ? item : (item.expectSt || '');
          return [...arr, ...node.split('.').filter(a => a)]
      }, []);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below which uses `for-in`:

```
const questionReferencesUpdate = {
    5:{
         1: "i was send to earth. i was send to her.",
         2: "to mars",
          3: { reference: "To moon.", expectSt: "to moon. to us." } ,
    }
};

let currentSlide = 1;
let arr = [];
for (let key in questionReferencesUpdate) {
  currentSlide = key;
  for (let keyX in questionReferencesUpdate[key]) {
    if (typeof questionReferencesUpdate[key][keyX] === 'string') {
      arr.push(questionReferencesUpdate[key][keyX]);
    } else {
      let reference = '';
      let expectSt = '';
      if ('reference' in questionReferencesUpdate[key][keyX]) {
        reference = questionReferencesUpdate[key][keyX]['reference'];
        arr.push(reference);
      }
      if ('expectSt' in questionReferencesUpdate[key][keyX]) {
        var searchMask = reference;
        var regEx = new RegExp(searchMask, "ig");
    
        expectSt = questionReferencesUpdate[key][keyX]['expectSt'].replace(regEx, '');
        arr.push(expectSt);
      }
    }
  }
}
arr = arr.filter(r => !!r); // remove empty entries
```

I typed this in mobile so if you see any typos just correct those.

Comment: Question ended by the time I posted my answer. Lol. I took the long route. =))